# Internet Explorer 10 Printing URL Below Link

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

When printing a web page in Internet Explorer 10, the browser is printing the URL of each link directly below the actual link itself.

Here is a screenshot:
http://prntscr.com/1gvz8x

Is there a way to turn this off via HTML/CSS or Javascript or is this a 'feature' of ie10?

Comment: Does it work in chrome, or firefox? If so then I would just use one of them and forget about IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is not the result of a browser setting but rather is due to some clever CSS in the page's print style sheet. Visiting the site shown in your screenshot using another browser (FF) and printing has equivalent output.

Removing the following rule from the 'Print styles' section of [style.css](http://oldsattorney.com/wp-content/themes/pa-grangeville-law/style.css) would prevent the printing of URLs after each link.
`a[href]:after { content: " (" attr(href) ")"; }`

Comment: Twitter Bootstrap also has this in the "print.less"

Answer (score -1):

I am using Bootstrap 3.3.7 and had this problem.  I found the same section in bootstrap.min.css.

I removed  **a[href]:after { content: " (" attr(href) ")"; }** 
and normal printing resumed.

Comment: This appears to be a comment agreeing with the answer by am2, and not a new answer to the question.

Comment: So you’re identifying a different CSS file in which the offending rule can appear? This should be a comment on the other answer.